# Delimeter-escaping edge case for Redshift

Tags: java, escaping, amazon-redshift

In my application, I take some events, write them to a logfile, and then I write them to redshift. The file below shows three cases. In one case, everything is normal, no pipes used. The second use case has a pipe, but it's escaped just fine. However, the third case is a bit tricker. `Event.x=Hi\|`, so that means escaping it will produce `Hi\\|`, and I don't know how Redshift will interpret this. Will it a) interpret it as an escaped backslash, and interpret the pipe as a regular delimiter (bad)? or b) only look at backslashes before pipes and still escape the pipe (good)?

```
In my Java code   ;Logfile Text  ;Redshift columns     ;Works
--------------------------------------------------------------
Event.x ;Event.y  ;Logfile Text  ;Column X  ;Column Y  ;Works
--------------------------------------------------------------
Hi      ;10       ;Hi|10         ;Hi        ;10        ;Yes
--------------------------------------------------------------
Hi|     ;10       ;Hi\||10       ;Hi|       ;10        ;Yes
--------------------------------------------------------------
Hi\|    ;10       ;Hi\\||10      ;???       ;???       ;???
```

Here is my code for escaping and joining the attributes currently. Assume `attributes` is a `List<String>`.

```
String log = attributes.stream()
    .map(s -> s.replace("|", "\\|"))    // Escape existing delimiters
    .collect(Collectors.joining("|"));  // Join on pipes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the escape and escape the pipe:  `"\|" -> "\\\|"`

e.g.

```
.map(s -> s.replace("\\", "\\\\"))  // Escape escapes
.map(s -> s.replace("|", "\\|"))    // Escape existing delimiters
```

From [redshift docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-format.html#copy-format):

> COPY loads \n as a newline character and loads \t as a tab character.
>   To load a backslash, escape it with a backslash ( \ ).

Comment: Ahh, what a simple and good solution. I will award bounty in 22 hours.